# put a value into hashmap which uses wildcard in java can not assign value

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, dictionary, wildcard

I am studying Generics in java.
I made a Map and initialized with 'new HashMap>()'.
After that, I made an ArrayList to put into that variable.
However, this code can not compile.

error message is:

"The method put(String, capture#1-of ? extends List) in the type Map> is not applicable for the arguments (String, List)"

on Map.put() method.

My code is below.

```
package org.owls.generic.main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> tmpArr = new ArrayList<String>();
        tmpArr.add("A");
        tmpArr.add("B");
        List<?> value = new ArrayList<String>(tmpArr);
        Map<String, ? extends List<String>> testMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        testMap.put("K", value);
    }
};
```

I can not understand why compiler looks  type, even I assigned inheritanced Class which is 'List'.

Sorry for my poor English and edit will be welcomed. 
Thanks for your answer:D

Comment: `? extends List<String>` is not a supertype of `List<?>`.

Comment: Is there a reason you used wildcards? Are you experimenting with wildcards, or are you just trying to make it work?

Comment: @Bohemian It's just for Java study:)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth So how can I put some type of Collection into Map<String, ?>? After I saw your comment, I changed List<?> value to ArrayList<String> value but still can not put it into Map. Is there any ideas?:)

Comment: @JuneyoungOh: You cannot put any value except `null` into a `Map<String, ?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot put anything except `null` into a generic type with the `? extends ...` parameter. This is basic Generics -- since the type parameter is unknown, you cannot put anything into it because whatever you try to put is not guaranteed to be a subtype of that unknown type.

Recall the PECS (Producer `extends`, Consumer `super`) rule. `? extends` can only be used for producers. Putting something in is a Consumer.

Comment: Thanks. Now I realize that I have tried something impossible:D