# Java Generics & jOOQ - How can I create a HashMap of one jOOQ column to another

Tags: java, inheritance, jooq

I have an interface

```
public interface HistoryDao<B extends UpdatableRecord<B>, H extends UpdatableRecord<H>> extends TableDao<H>{
    default void saveHistoryForIds(List<Integer> ids) {
        HashMap<? extends TableField<H, ? extends TableField<H, ? extends Serializable>>, ? extends TableField<B, ? extends TableField<B, ? extends Serializable>>> mappings = setUpHistoryMapping();

        List<? extends TableField<H, ? extends Serializable>> tableFields = new ArrayList<>(mappings.keySet());

        ArrayList<H> hs = new ArrayList<>();
        jooq()
            .insertInto(table(), tableFields);

    }

    HashMap<? extends TableField<H, ? extends TableField<H, ? extends Serializable>>, ? extends TableField<B, ? extends TableField<B, ? extends Serializable>>> setUpHistoryMapping();
}
```

(TableDao is an interface but it's not super important)

And In my concrete class I try to implement

```
MyClassHere implements HistoryDao<ApprovalWorkflowRecord, ApprovalWorkflowHistoryRecord>

@Override
public HashMap<? extends TableField<ApprovalWorkflowHistoryRecord, ? extends TableField<ApprovalWorkflowHistoryRecord, ? extends Serializable>>, ? extends TableField<ApprovalWorkflowRecord, ? extends TableField<ApprovalWorkflowRecord, ? extends Serializable>>> setUpHistoryMapping() {
    HashMap<? extends TableField<ApprovalWorkflowHistoryRecord, ? extends TableField<ApprovalWorkflowHistoryRecord, ? extends Serializable>>, ? extends TableField<ApprovalWorkflowRecord, ? extends TableField<ApprovalWorkflowRecord, ? extends Serializable>>> x = new HashMap<>();

    TableField<ApprovalWorkflowHistoryRecord, Integer> id = APPROVAL_WORKFLOW_HISTORY.ID;

    x.put(id, APPROVAL_WORKFLOW.ID);
}
```

I think my issue is something to do with covariance... (maybe) but I keep getting this error

> x.put(id, APPROVAL_WORKFLOW.ID);
>
> ```
> method Map.put(CAP#1,CAP#2) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; TableField<ApprovalWorkflowHistoryRecord,Integer> cannot be converted to CAP#1)
>
> method AbstractMap.put(CAP#1,CAP#2) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; TableField<ApprovalWorkflowHistoryRecord,Integer> cannot be converted to CAP#1)
>
> method HashMap.put(CAP#1,CAP#2) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; TableField<ApprovalWorkflowHistoryRecord,Integer> cannot be converted to CAP#1)   where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
> CAP#1 extends TableField<ApprovalWorkflowHistoryRecord,? extends TableField<ApprovalWorkflowHistoryRecord,? extends Serializable>> from capture of ? extends TableField<ApprovalWorkflowHistoryRecord,? extends TableField<ApprovalWorkflowHistoryRecord,? extends Serializable>> CAP#2 extends TableField<ApprovalWorkflowRecord,? extends TableField<ApprovalWorkflowRecord,? extends Serializable>> from capture of ? extends TableField<ApprovalWorkflowRecord,? extends TableField<ApprovalWorkflowRecord,? extends Serializable>>
> ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you ignore all the (admittedly impressive) generic noise, your problem boils down to the classic problem of putting a value in a collection with wildcards:

```
Map<?, ?> x = new HashMap<>();
x.put("a", "b"); // Doesn't work.
```

Just remove all the wildcards where you don't need them and replace them by concrete types. As a general rule of thumb:

- Use wild cards in method arguments to allow method callers to pass some less specific collections.
- Use wild cards when you put generic types into collections, e.g. `List<Class<?>>` or in this case `List<TableField<H, ?>>`.
- Try to avoid returning wildcards from methods.

Here's how to fix this in your case:

```
public interface HistoryDao<
    B extends UpdatableRecord<B>, 
    H extends UpdatableRecord<H>
> extends TableDao<H> {
    default void saveHistoryForIds(List<Integer> ids) {
        HashMap<TableField<H, ?>, TableField<B, ?>> mappings = setUpHistoryMapping();
        List<TableField<H, ?>> tableFields = new ArrayList<>(mappings.keySet());
        jooq().insertInto(table(), tableFields);
    }

    HashMap<TableField<H, ?>, TableField<B, ?>> setUpHistoryMapping();
}

class MyClassHere implements HistoryDao<
    ApprovalWorkflowRecord, 
    ApprovalWorkflowHistoryRecord
> {

    @Override
    public HashMap<
        TableField<ApprovalWorkflowHistoryRecord, ?>, 
        TableField<ApprovalWorkflowRecord, ?>
    > setUpHistoryMapping() {
        HashMap<
            TableField<ApprovalWorkflowHistoryRecord, ?>, 
            TableField<ApprovalWorkflowRecord, ?>
        > x = new HashMap<>();

        x.put(APPROVAL_WORKFLOW_HISTORY.ID, APPROVAL_WORKFLOW.ID);
    }
}
```

What did I change?

- Local `Map` types don't use wildcards on their keys / values anymore. Instead of `Map<? extends TableField<...>, ? extends TableField<...>>`, just write `Map<TableField<...>, TableField<...>>`
- The same is true for the `setUpHistoryMapping()` method's return type.
- You don't need `? extends Serializable` here. That type bound doesn't add any value. Just use `?` instead.
- You nested `TableField<?, TableField<...>>` by accident. That doesn't make sense in a jOOQ context.

See also:

- [Problem using generic map with wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1921237/521799)
- [put a value into hashmap which uses wildcard in java can not assign value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20558007/521799)
- [Using Java Generics with HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19275285/521799)
- [Java Map compiler error with generic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17213301/521799)
- [What is wrong with my method generic parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22987844/521799)

Comment: Yes!! Thank you so much. I was definitely struggling a lot with the wild cards and this makes a lot of sense. Thanks for all the additional info too!